# Proving that the field $Q$ is ordered using the order axioms for a field

Tags: field-theory, rational-numbers

I'm trying to prove that the field $Q$ (the rationals) is ordered using the order axioms for a field.

The order axioms for a field $F$ with $a,b,c \in F$:

1. For $a$ and $b$ only one of the below can be true:

i) $a<b$

ii) $b<a$

iii) $b=a$

2. If $a<b$ and $b<c$ then $a<c$.
3. If $a<b$ then $a+c<b+c$.
4. If $a<b$ then $ac<bc$ for 0

I started by defining 1.i),ii),iii) for $\frac{a}{b}, \frac{c}{d} \in Q$. Then I tried to prove that $\frac{a}{b}, \frac{c}{d}, \frac{e}{f} \in Q$ satisfy properties 2.,3, and 4. but the proofs for all of them didn't really work out since 2.,3. and 4. all seem too axiomatic. For instance for 2., I started with $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}$ and $\frac{c}{d}<\frac{e}{f}$ and said $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}<\frac{e}{f} \to \frac{a}{b}<\frac{e}{f}$ but I'm not sure if this is a proof more than it is a simple restatement of the axiom. My other proofs were very similar so I'm wondering if there's any special tricks or anything which I have to do.

Comment: First off, you need to _define_ the $<$ you're using. Without definitions there can be no proofs. For instance, one might define $\frac ab < \frac cd \iff ad-bc < 0$ where the second inequality is an inequality of integers (this works as long as we require $b$ and $d$ to be positive). Your book should have a definition, which might be different. Once you have a definition, you can start proving the properties it might or might not have.

Comment: @Arthur - you forgot "with $b$ and $d$ positive..."

Comment: @peterag That was it! I knew there was something fishy going on.